# Sort data when writing to excel

Tags: java, excel

I have a collection of object as below:

```
Collection<OrderData> orderDataCollection = new ArrayList<OrderData>();
```

and want to write it in excel, So how can I sort this data?

Comment: Use collections.sort(orderDataCollection)

Comment: see collections.sort() method

Comment: I have a collection of object below:
    Collection<OrderData> orderDataCollection = new ArrayList<OrderData>();

adding OrderData objets from different different tables based on search and then trying to write orderDataCollection data in excel file  but the order of data in excel file is not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Collections.sort(orderDataCollection);
```

Comment: Collections's `sort` method does not return anything !

Comment: Getting The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<OrderData>) error.

Comment: You need to implement the compareTo method in your OrderData class.

Comment: I have a collection of object below:
    Collection<OrderData> orderDataCollection = new ArrayList<OrderData>();

adding OrderData objets from different different tables based on search and then trying to write orderDataCollection data in excel file  but the order of data in excel file is not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method

```
Collections.sort(orderDataCollection);
```

Comment: I have a collection of object below:
    Collection<OrderData> orderDataCollection = new ArrayList<OrderData>();

adding OrderData objets from different different tables based on search and then trying to write orderDataCollection data in excel file  but the order of data in excel file is not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(orderDataCollection);
```

If this isn't what you were looking for be more specific about what you want to do and what you have.

Comment: I have a collection of object below:
    Collection<OrderData> orderDataCollection = new ArrayList<OrderData>();

adding OrderData objets from different different tables based on search and then trying to write orderDataCollection data in excel file  but the order of data in excel file is not maintained.